# google api moments error Google.GoogleApiException

Tags: google-plus

I am using Google API
I try to insert moments but I get error:
    Google.GoogleApiException was unhandled
    Message=An Error occurred, but the error response could not be deserialized
      Source=Google.Apis
      ServiceName=tasks

my code:

// Create the service.

```
var service = new TasksService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()  
    {                 
        Authenticator = auth
    });
    TaskLists results = service.Tasklists.List().Execute();

//it's work fine


        Moment body = new Moment();
            ItemScope target = new ItemScope();
            target.Id = "replacewithuniqueforaddtarget";
            target.Image = "http://www.google.com/s2/static/images/GoogleyEyes.png";
            target.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";
            target.Description = "The description for the activity";
            target.Name = "An example of add activity";
            body.Target = target;
            body.Target.Url = "https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/widget";
            body.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";

            MomentsResource.InsertRequest insert = new MomentsResource.InsertRequest(service, body, "me", MomentsResource.Collection.Vault);
            Moment wrote = insert.Execute(); //error here
```

Comment: Try enabling verbose debugging:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459215/google-android-api-plusclient-writemoment-is-doing-nothing/16465480#16465480

Comment: it's .net application

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is either set the target URL or set the other metadata inside of the moment body. If you are setting both, you will get an error. The following code should work:

```
ItemScope target = new ItemScope();
// target.Id = "replacewithuniqueforaddtarget"; // This is optional.
target.Url = "https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/widget";

Moment body = new Moment();
body.Target = target;
body.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";

MomentsResource.InsertRequest insert = 
  new MomentsResource.InsertRequest(service, body, "me",
    MomentsResource.Collection.Vault);
Moment wrote = insert.Execute();
```

Or the following code:

```
ItemScope target = new ItemScope();
target.Id = "replacewithuniqueforaddtarget"; // Optional
target.Image = "http://www.google.com/s2/static/images/GoogleyEyes.png";
target.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";
target.Description = "The description for the activity";
target.Name = "An example of add activity";

Moment body = new Moment();
body.Target = target;
body.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";

MomentsResource.InsertRequest insert = 
  new MomentsResource.InsertRequest(service, body, "me",
    MomentsResource.Collection.Vault);
Moment wrote = insert.Execute();
```

I just tested the above code with the 1.4 library, this should work in either case.

It's possible that you are not creating a Google+ service client but instead are just creating the Tasks service client and trying to use that.  The following boilerplate is a full example that constructs a Google+ service and writes a moment:

```
            // Register the authenticator and construct the Plus service
            // for performing API calls on behalf of the user.
            _authState = YOUR_AUTHSTATE_OBJECT;
            AuthorizationServerDescription description =
                GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description;
            var provider = new WebServerClient(description);
            provider.ClientIdentifier = CLIENT_ID;
            provider.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;
            var authenticator =
                new OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient>(
                    provider,
                    GetAuthorization)
                {
                    NoCaching = true
                };
            ps = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
              Authenticator = authenticator
            });

            Moment body = new Moment();
            body.Target = target;
            body.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";

            MomentsResource.InsertRequest insert =
              new MomentsResource.InsertRequest(ps, body, "me",
                MomentsResource.Collection.Vault);
            Moment wrote = insert.Execute();
```

Comment: The same error.
Also I get this error when I trying next code:

MomentsResource.ListRequest listRequest = new MomentsResource.ListRequest(service, "me", MomentsResource.CollectionEnum.Vault);
            MomentsFeed momentsList = listRequest.Execute();

Comment: Can you tell me more information about your development environment? You mentioned .NET, which library version and programming language are you using?

Comment: c# form application, framework 4.0, google.APis 1.4.0.28227, google.apis.Authentication.OAuth2 1.4.0.28223, Google.apis.plus.v1 1.4.0.28200, google.apis.tasks.v1 1.4.0.28200, dotNetOpenAuth 4.0.0.11165, Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.0.0

Comment: Maybe you are using your Tasks service client instead of a Plus service client?

Comment: My code: 
private IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient client)
        {
            String[] reqAuthScopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me" };           
            if (_authstate == null)
            {                
                _authstate = new AuthorizationState(reqAuthScopes);                        
                Uri requestURL = client.RequestUserAuthorization(reqAuthScopes);
                Uri url = client.RequestUserAuthorization(reqAuthScopes);

Comment: String authCode = //get pin code using webbrowser                
                
                IAuthorizationState state = client.ProcessUserAuthorization(new Uri("http://localhost"), _authstate);
               
                return client.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
            }
            
            return null;
        } I am get error: Google.GoogleApiException was unhandled
  Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Insufficient Permission [403]

Comment: I am using your code. When I add next code PeopleResource.GetRequest grrrr = ps.People.Get("me");

            Google.Apis.Plus.v1.Data.Person me = grrrr.Execute(); I get my data. But error change to: System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
  Message=Error in the precondition.: authorization != null Also my function GetAuthorization always called after command .Execute(); Is it right?

Comment: Pin code: in browser title I see only the half of pin code. But in html document I see all code. Which code to use?

Comment: 1) You only need a single PlusService object for making multiple API calls and should only initialize it once. Again, it looks like your service object (var service = ...) is not a PlusService but instead is the service client for tasks. 2) For the authorization code, you will need the entire one-time-code but only for when you exchange the code for an access/refresh token. The client library should be handling code exchange to get you an access token and refresh token. 3) If you are able to perform plus.get('me') successfully, your client is working - is requestvisibleactions in your auth?

Comment: Plus service: PlusService ps = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                Authenticator = authenticator                
            }); Authorization: IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { PlusService.Scopes.PlusLogin.GetStringValue() }); Also I store refresh token. I am executing next lines without errots: MomentsResource.ListRequest listRequest = new MomentsResource.ListRequest(ps, me.Id, MomentsResource.CollectionEnum.Vault);
            MomentsFeed momentsList = listRequest.Execute(); But it returns 0 items

Comment: After: MomentsResource.InsertRequest insert =
              new MomentsResource.InsertRequest(ps, body, "me",
                MomentsResource.Collection.Vault);
            Moment wrote = insert.Execute(); I get error: System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
  Message=Ошибка в предусловии.: authorization != null
  Source=Google.Apis What is correct result of insert moments. How can I view moments in my google+ profile?