# How to post activity on Google Plus

Tags: c#, google-plus

I have tried this code

```
PlusService plus = new PlusService(
    new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        ApiKey = "..."
    });
Moment body = new Moment();
ItemScope target = new ItemScope();
target.Url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543726/google-api-moments-error-google-googleapiexception";
target.Id = "103692090766566349707";
target.Description = "The description for the activity";
target.Name = "An example of add activity";
body.Target = target;
body.Type = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";
//var m = plus.Moments.Insert(body,"me", MomentsResource.InsertRequest.CollectionEnum.Vault).Execute();
MomentsResource.InsertRequest insert = 
    new MomentsResource.InsertRequest(plus, body, 
        "103692090766566349707", MomentsResource.InsertRequest.CollectionEnum.Vault);
var momentsResource = plus.Activities.List("me", ActivitiesResource.ListRequest.CollectionEnum.Public);
Moment wrote = insert.Execute();// error Here
```

and the error message is

> Could not load file or assembly 'Zlib.Portable, Version=1.9.1.9000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I assume that assembly is in your bin folder?

Comment: You might want to remove that APIKey.

Comment: You'll actually want to reset the API key and get a new one from Google.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a simple API key which will not authorize the user. Sign the user in as demonstrated in the [Google+ Photohunt sample](https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/csharp#app_activities) and then you will be able to write app activities.

For the authorization step, authorize the user as demonstrated here:

https://github.com/gguuss/google-dotnet-demo/blob/master/AuthWithAppActivities/Program.cs

```
    // These come from the APIs console:
    //   https://code.google.com/apis/console
    public static ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets()
    {
        ClientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
        ClientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
    };
```

...

```
        UserCredential credential;

        var initializer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = secrets,
            Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin}
        };
        var flow = new AAGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(initializer);
        credential = await new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerCodeReceiver()).AuthorizeAsync
            ("user", CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Create the service.
        var service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Gus API",
            });
```

Also, you will need to modify the authorization URL handler to add the app activity types:

```
public class AAGoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl : GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl
{
    [Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterAttribute("request_visible_actions", Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterType.Query)]
    public string VisibleActions { get; set; }

    public AAGoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(Uri authorizationServerUrl)
        : base(authorizationServerUrl)
    {
    }
}

public class AAGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow : AuthorizationCodeFlow
{
    /// <summary>Constructs a new Google authorization code flow.</summary>
    public AAGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(AuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer initializer)
        : base(initializer)
    {
    }

    public override AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(string redirectUri)
    {
        return new AAGoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(new Uri(AuthorizationServerUrl))
        {
            ClientId = ClientSecrets.ClientId,
            Scope = string.Join(" ", Scopes),
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            VisibleActions = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
        };
    }
}
```

This will authorize the user for app activities (on the console) but you probably should be using client-side authorization. For that, use something like [the Google+ quickstart sample](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart) and authorize the user both on the javascript client and the server.

Comment: I gone through the link which you suggested but unable to get solution.

Comment: You also need to request the plus.login scope for app activities.