# Moments.Insert with URL returns bad request (400) error code

Tags: c#, .net, google-plus, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to insert a moment on a Google+ App using the .NET Libraries given by Google. I need to use the URL (it's a requirement) but it always give me the 400 error code (bad request) after executing the Insert. Code is something like this (I got it from the sample app for login button, nothing fancy!)

```
 if (context.Request.Path.Contains("/moment"))
  {
     Moment moment = new Moment();
     moment.Type = "http://schema.org/AddAction";
     ItemScope itemScope = new ItemScope();
     itemScope.Id= "target-id-1";
     itemScope.Url = "anyURLyoucanthink";  

     moment.Target = itemScope;
     Moment momentResult = ps.Moments.Insert(moment, gplus_id,
     MomentsResource.InsertRequest.CollectionEnum.Vault).Execute();
  }
```

I tried different URLs and that's not the problem I think. One thing that really caught my attention is that on the Google+ Documentation for Moments Insert ([Here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert)) the .NET example is the only one that doesn't have an "with URL" and "without URL" examples, all the other options have those. Maybe it isn't supported anymore with a newer version?.

Thanks!.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Look http://stackoverflow.com/a/15289126/1241400 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17553897/1241400.